1 Hz pulse generator using 1ppm TCXO - review
The goal is to calibrate an RTC clock in a device that will operate in the field for up to 15 years while maintaining the highest possible accuracy in terms of time deviation.
The calibration is carried out using a production tester, where the 1 Hz, 1 ppm PCB will be interfaced with the device requiring calibration.
I need an output of 1 Hz with an amplitude of 3.6 V.
To achieve this, I am designing a PCBA intended to provide a 1 Hz frequency with 1 ppm accuracy.
I will use the SiT7910AI-1QYY-B32.768F TCXO to accomplish this.


List of components:

I will connect an external LDO to the circuit, which supplies ~3.5 V under load.
Do you have any suggestions for improving the circuit or components to achieve the best results?

If I understand right, the circuit in the schematic will be used as production tester? In this case you might want to output a much higher frequency, because you don‘t want to wait a very long time until your DUT is calibrated.

This is an exact duplicate of your previous question, which you never acknowledged to have a solution.

Also, how good results you want? You say "highest possible" but settle on a 1 ppm? Your BOM does not match the schematics either.

If you are going to use generator "in field",  how you are a going to compensate freq instability due to temperature change?

This is not how I would calibrate an RTC.  I would use a high speed ripple counter with LEDs and an XOR Mixer with the 32 kHz clock and an ultrastable 32 kHz reference 0.01 ppm  32k clock into mixer then 10 LEDs you can tune RTC in a few seconds to null the sliding edge of the LEDs for a null frequency error.  THe RTC should be in a double oven. (ultraminiature)  The RTC will get aging, mechanical, & climatic errors and never be the best possible RTC.  $20 GPS chip might do the trick.

Is the only difference from the previous question a change from a SiT7910AI-1Q18-B32.768 (supply voltage 1.8 V nominal) to a SiT7910AI-1QYY-B32.768F (supply voltage 1.62 to 3.63 V)? If so, you should [edit] the question to make this clear, to prevent it being closed as a duplicate of the previous question. There is already one duplicate close vote on this question.

You don't say what it's for, but note: 1) 15 years at 1ppm is about 8 minutes, enough to be a problem for simple time-of-day stamping, 2) you won't know about leap seconds.  If it's some kind of data collector, how does the data get out?  Surely you could do something even with periodic collector (SNTP against a phone?)  You don't say why you can't use GPS, but if it's reception, consider MSF, DCF77 or similar which are often receivable when GPS is not.  You're spending a lot of effort to make timekeeping good, perhaps it's easier to solve communication.
